# Sending Parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't know which part of the code is wrong.

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddNewNews
(@title nvarchar(50),
 @text ntext,
 @year int,
 @month int,
 @day int,
 @id_writer int ,
 @id_subject1 int,
 @id_subject2 int,
 @id_subject3 int,
 @id_subject4 int,
 @id_subject5 int)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

     DECLARE @last_id_news int
     BEGIN TRY

        insert into news(title, text, year, month, day, id_writer)
        values(@title, @text, @year, @month, @day, @id_writer)

        set @last_id_news = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

if @id_subject1 is not null
begin
    insert into news_subject (id_news,id_subject) values (@last_id_news,@id_subject1)
end
if @id_subject2 is not null
begin
    insert into news_subject (id_news,id_subject) values (@last_id_news,@id_subject2)
end
if @id_subject3 is not null
begin
    insert into news_subject (id_news,id_subject) values (@last_id_news,@id_subject3)
end
if @id_subject4 is not null 
begin
    insert into news_subject (id_news,id_subject) values (@last_id_news,@id_subject4)
end
if @id_subject5 is not null
begin
    insert into news_subject (id_news,id_subject) values (@last_id_news,@id_subject5)
end

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

RETURN
```

and this is how I send the parameters to the stored procedure from my C# code:

```
public bool AddNewNews(News news, List<object> subject)
{
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter ("@title", news.Id_news),
        new SqlParameter ("@text", news.Text),
        new SqlParameter ("@year", news.Year),
        new SqlParameter ("@month", news.Month),
        new SqlParameter ("@day", news.Day),
        new SqlParameter ("@id_writer", news.Id_writer),
        new SqlParameter ("@id_subject1", subject[0]),
        new SqlParameter ("@id_subject2", subject[1]),
        new SqlParameter ("@id_subject3", subject[2]),
        new SqlParameter ("@id_subject4", subject[3]),
        new SqlParameter ("@id_subject5", subject[4])
    };
    return SqlDBHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("AddNewNews", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
}
```

Just the subject[i] can be null

but I don't know when it goes to the stored procedure and check `id_subject` is false or Other part of code?

Comment: What error appears? You can also put a breakpoint in the last return so you can see all parameters value

Comment: this is error: Procedure or function 'AddNewNews' expects parameter '@id_subject3', which was not supplied.

Comment: It's a **STORED** procedure - as in **STORED** inside your SQL Server. It has nothing to do with a "store" ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the parameters to your stored proc to have defaults:

```
@id_subject1 int = null,
@id_subject2 int = null,
@id_subject3 int = null,
@id_subject4 int = null,
@id_subject5 int = null
```

Comment: When he passes null values, the values are not sent to the stored proc?

Comment: @NicolasR When NULL value is passed the parameter is ignored.

Comment: thank you very much it work . I worked for 7 hours. But I can not find it

Answer (score 1):

> "just the subject[i] can be null but i don't know when it goes to the store procedure and check id_subject is false or other part of code?"

If I understand you correctly, then those `subject[i]` values may be `null`. Passing the value `null` doesn't work - the value won't be passed correctly.

Instead, send the parameters to your stored procedure like this:

```
new SqlParameter ("@id_subject3",subject[2] ?? DBNull.Value)
```